# How to make it so a specific entry isn't added to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code so that I can add some students to a list, but I also have a line where if they enter a blank string it takes the user back to the menu. However, when I enter the blank string it also adds that to the list of students. How can I change that?

```
students = []

ans = True
while ans:
    print ("""
a.Add new students
b.Show student list
c.Delete a student
d.Exit
""")
ans = input("What would you like to do? ") 

if ans == "a": 
  enterStudent = input ("Enter a new student name:")
  students = [enterStudent]
  while enterStudent != "": #loop to enter multiple student names
      enterStudent = input ("Enter a new student name:")
      students.append (enterStudent)
      print ("The list now contains the students :",students)
elif ans == "b":
    print("\n The current student list is:")
    print (*students,sep='\n')
elif ans == "c": #delete a student from the list.
    removeStudent = input ("Enter a student name to delete:") 
    students.remove (removeStudent)
elif ans == "d":
    print("\n Goodbye")
elif ans != "":
    print("\n Try again")
```

Output:

```
 What would you like to do? a
 Enter a new student name:Bob Bob
 Enter a new student name:Bob Bob
 The list now contains the students : ['Bob Bob', 'Bob Bob']
 Enter a new student name:
 The list now contains the students : ['Bob Bob', 'Bob Bob', '']
```

Another problem I have is that after I enter two names of students, it prints the list out before the user enters a blank string.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You're testing whether the student name is blank **after** you've already done `students.append(enterStudent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a line to check if the line that contains the student name was blank, and in such case, return to the menu by exiting the while loop

Also, the first time that you ask for a student name is actually not used. I would delete the two lines on top of the while and instead, just assign a non-blank value to enterStudent. So I would change this:

```
  enterStudent = input ("Enter a new student name:")
  students = [enterStudent]
  while enterStudent != "": #loop to enter multiple student names
      enterStudent = input ("Enter a new student name:")
      students.append (enterStudent)
      print ("The list now contains the students :",students)
```

To this:

```
  students = []
  enterStudent = "goIntoWhile"
  while enterStudent != "": #loop to enter multiple student names
      enterStudent = input ("Enter a new student name:")
      if enterStudent == "":
          break
      students.append (enterStudent)
      print ("The list now contains the students :",students)
```

Comment: This will allow the first student name to be blank.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thanks Barmar! No problem wndzyo

Comment: What's the point of doing the test in `while` when you break out of the loop first?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop isn't testing whether the student name is blank until it goes back to the top of the loop, which is after it adds the entry the list. Try:

```
students = []
while True:
    enterStudent = input("Enter a new student name:")
    if not enterStudent:
        break
    students.append(enterStudent)
    print ("The list now contains the students :",students)
```

Comment: I think this solution is cleaner and more idiomatic than the accepted answer.